# Username and Password In SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I use SQL Server Reporting Services for reporting purpose and create reporting using and attach database then when I deploy any report it shows me username and password in SQL Server Reporting Service.

So what does it mean by password and username and where do I get this username and password for SQL Server Reporting Service?

Here is a picture

[image]

So what can I do?

Comment: What browser is this in? Do you see anything at all in your browser or does this just come up? It looks like you have secured the virtual directory in your IIS. Try setting it to anonymous authentication in IIS.

Comment: in visual studio when i deploy me report then this box is appear and how i set setting  to anonymous authentication in IIS???

Comment: ???????????? nay help please

Answer (score 0):

The password prompt is for access to the SQL database. You need to set this in your datasource based on what you need to avoid the prompts. You can use AD, SQL Authentication, etc.